# how to use between with laravel query builder

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use `BETWEEN` with laravel query builder. How do I do it. I have tried this below

```
Eventcalender::where(['between', 'acceptance_date', $final, $time])->count();
```

Comment: I don't think you can use 'between' like this. Instead, use `whereBetween`. Check the Laravel doc here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries

Answer (score 6):

Check hist out: [whereBetween()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

The **whereBetween** method verifies that a column's value is **between two values**,

#### For Eloquent:

```php
Eventcalender::whereBetween('acceptance_date', [$final, $time])->count();
```

#### For Query Builder:

```php
DB::table('eventcalenders')->whereBetween('acceptance_date', [$final, $time])->count();
```